# Conflicting answers gained from different equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

First time posting I hope this is the place.

**if someone could help me sort out formatting for the equations that would be nice**

*"As a result of being hit from behind by a toy truck, a 50g toy car rolls 3.0m across a floor that applies a constant retarding force of 1.2N to it. The car stops 2.0s after being hit. If the truck was in a contact with the ball for 0.15s calculate the impulse given to the car"*

I started off this question by calculating the acceleration acting on the ball after the impact

\begin{eqnarray*}
F &=& ma\\
\therefore F/m &=& a\\
\therefore -1.2/0.05 &=& a = -24ms^{-2}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Now from this I attempted to calculate the initial velocity strait after the impact. This is there the problems began. Using the equasion

\begin{eqnarray*}
v^2 &=& u^2 + 2as\\
0^2 &=& u^2 + 2 * -24 * 3\\
u^2 &=& 144\\
u &=& 12ms^{-1}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

**But**

\begin{eqnarray*}
(v-u)/t &=& a\\ 
(0-u)/2 &=& -24\\
-u &=& -48\\
u &=& 48ms^{-1}\\ 
\end{eqnarray*}

Why do these two equasions yield different results

Comment: The question appears to be overspecified.  I can't come up with a self-consistent interpretation.

Comment: Note also the random introduction of a "ball" to the truck-car collision...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is inconsistent. At least one of the numbers (mass, force, stopping distance, or stopping time) is wrong. Your calculation of the acceleration from force and mass is correct, but an acceleration of $24$ m/s$^2$ for $2$ seconds means that the toy car was initially traveling at $48$ m/s. This is over $100$ mph ($160$ kph) and there is no way the car is stopping in only $3$ meters. The actual stopping distance in $2$ seconds is $48$ meters. This isn't necessarily what the question writer had in mind, so we don't know what the real answer should be.